# puppeteer headless = 'new' | false not working properly

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm currently trying to build a small tool using node.js and puppeteer to find out which external files are loaded on a website. This works fine with the option headless: true. however, in the future this will become indifferent to headless: 'new'. so I've already used headless: 'new' to test. Then I found out that with this option many less requests are shown.

on the same website with (headless: true) I get **10 external requests**, and with (headless: 'new') or (headless:false) I only get **2 external requests**. has anyone had the same problem. Or does anyone know where this difference comes from.

Many thanks in advance for any answer.

here my function:

```
export async function getExternalFonts (url) {
    const containHttpS = /^https?:\/\//i;

    if(!containHttpS.test(url)) {
        url = `http://${url}`;
    }

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: 'new'});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
 
    
    // Activate Request-Monitoring
    await page.setRequestInterception(true);

    const externalLinks = [];

    // Eventlistener for all requests
    page.on('request', (request) => {
        
        // Domain to compare.
        const domain = extractDomain(url);
        if(!request.url().includes(domain)){
            
            //add results to array
            externalLinks.push({
                url: request.url(),
                type: request.resourceType(),
                method: request.method(),
                headers: request.headers()
            });
            request.continue();
        }
        else{
            request.continue();
        }
    });
  
    await page.goto(url);
    await browser.close();
  
    console.log("external links count:",externalLinks.length);
    return externalLinks;
}
```